# Does Google index page returned from Servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, url, servlets

Previously I thought Google does not index pages returned from Servlets. However, I suddenly found some urls that confused me.
Just take the url of this page as example, it has the following pattern:

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/p1/p2)

where p1 is some number, and p2 is the title of this question.
Imagine the website is built in Java (JSP), I guess there is a servlet mapping to /questions/p1/p2. However, this page is indeed indexed by Google. So, does Google index pages returned from servlets? Or where am I wrong?


Extended question: How to dynamically create a webpage? Taking 4shared.com as an example, when a user uploads a file, a new page is dynamically created, and url ends with ".html". e.g.: [Link](http://www.4shared.com/mp3/EJWay2TR/After_School_-_First_Love.html)

How is this done? Anyone knows the mechanism? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't know, and doesn't care, how the pages are generated. And most of the pages on the web these days are dynamically generated. As long as it finds a link in some known page that points to another, it clicks on the link and indexes the page.

What Google can't index is pages protected by a password, or that are only accessible by filling a form.

Regarding your last question, I don't know 4shared.com, but creating a page dynamically is quite easy:

- the user uploads some document
- the server generates a unique ID for this document and stores it in the database
- when the server receives a request to /some_document_id, it extracts the ID from the URL, fetches the document from the database, and sends it as a response.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer, now I understands why these pages are indexed. As for the second question, I am more confused in the url. Since the url ends with ".html", so I guess a new html page is also created and stored on the server when a user uploads a file.

Comment: A URL is just an identifier. You can map a servlet to any URL, even if it ends with .html. The fact that the URL ends with .html doesn't mean that a physical html file exists on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Google can index the *bookmarkable* URLs, pages that can be reached via HTTP GET request with or without parameters. To obtain SEO friendly and easy to read URLs like the one you mention in your post I always use PrettyFaces, even if you can easily build something similar yourself (but there's no point in reinventing the wheel in case what avalaible is enough).

From the PrettyFaces website:

> PrettyFaces is an OpenSource URL-rewriting library with enhanced
>   support for JavaServer Faces – JSF 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0 – enabling
>   creation of bookmark-able, pretty URLs. PrettyFaces solves the
>   “RESTful URL” problem elegantly, including features such as: page-load
>   actions, seamless integration with faces navigation, dynamic view-id
>   assignment, managed parameter parsing, and configuration-free
>   compatibility with other web frameworks.

Have a look to http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/